# Getting ip from specific URL

Tags: c#, networking, ip

I'm trying to get the IP address of a specific url using:

```
var ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses("http://oldschool.runescape.com/game?world=321")[0];
```

The problem is that this function only seems to work with the normal host adress (as the function tells, ex: www.runescape.com) which creates an exception when using this specific more deeper URL. Is there any function to get the IP of a more specific URL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The full url like that will have the same hostname. As easy way to get the hostname is this:

```
var url = "http://oldschool.runescape.com/game?world=321";
Uri myUri = new Uri(url);
var ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(myUri.Host)[0];
```

Simply extract the host out of the url and that should prevent your error giving you the correct Ip address of the host.

Comment: This only works if there is only one Ethernet card.  When you have multiple Ethernet card you have to check for IP.  There is also an issue with loopback address 127.0.0.1 (localhost).  Each computer has a Host file and which contains every Ethernet card and loopback address.  Some computers have the local host and other do not.  Some have Ethernet card first and others have localhost first.  The GetHostAddress looks up entries in the Host file (in windows folder).  So the index may not be zero.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on DNS, however the "more specific" URL should be irrelevant as the IP for the host node is all you should need to care about. The rest of the subdomains still reside on the same box and should have the same IP Address. If for whatever reason what you are looking for is a hosted service within that domain, then it will have a different URL completely.

an NSLOOKUP for example would only return the root domain;

DNS server handling your query: localhost
 DNS server's address:  127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
 oldschool.runescape.com    canonical name = runescape.com.
 Name:  runescape.com
 Address: 91.235.140.130

However I do see that the URL you provided does redirect elsewhere to:     http://oldschool.runescape.com/slu

Hope this helps.